# AWS Lambda forbidden error via api gateway get request

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently working on aws and have an apigateway with one get request. I then have a lambda which i call via the api gateway.

So when i now call the gateway passing the accesstoken as generated from iam when logging in it throws an error

```
{
"message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I thought it might have been the gateway but it actually hits the lambda as i did console log in there. So not sure how else i can check what it can be.

I am using Lambda proxy integration.

Any tips?

Cheers

Comment: Your Lambda is being invoked for the request that gives you Unauthorized? Does you Lambda function fail with any errors?

Comment: it was actually a 502 error based on lambda function. It gave me the error in firefox and not chrome. However preflight issues exist on chrome

Comment: If it's a 502, enable API Gateway execution logs and check what the exact error message was.